# Can't reference Polly or other packages in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have tried the below in a version 4 Azure Function app

```
#r "Polly"
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

and/or

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Polly;
```

But in both cases it says Polly is not found. From the docs I tried to add a framework 46 reference too in the json file for the function app but that did not work. What is the best way to import a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One of the workaround to install Polly dependency injection in Azure Functions v4 is:**

- Open the Azure Functions V4 Project.
- Right-click on the project > Click on `Manage Nuget Packages`
- Install the required extensions for your project like

[image]

Start writing the code related to Polly policies extension in the function class like:

[image]

The ways to add the dependency injections in the Azure Functions is:

1. Installing the Dependency Injections using NuGet Package Manager by right clicking on the project.
   Or
2. Using the DotNet CLI or Package Manager commands available in the [NuGet official Site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly/).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to do it direct in the function.proj in the azure portal, but this helped me generate it